# Determine the layer of a packet in a pcap file created by tcpdump

Tags: pcap, libpcap, tcpdump

I was reading through the [libpcap tutorial](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) and was using some captures that I want to analyze (I didn't create them myself), so I am using the offline mode.

When applying the tutorial, nothing seemed to match. I didn't get valid MAC addresses from the ethernet frame and not even the preamble seemed to be correct. After some expirementing I fired up wireshark and noticed something odd. Each packet start with a `6`: These are not packets on the ethernet (data link) layer, they are already one layer up on the IP (network) layer (They are IPv6 packets, which is expected).

Of course, I can now easily continue, but I am still wondering: How do I know at which layer the captured packages are? It seems there are at least two options: Saving at the data link layer and saving at the network layer. Could it also be that I receive packets on the transport layer? How do I differentiate? Must the user tell me? I'd really hate to have to guess, but seeing as wireshark gets it right, there must be a simple way to determine it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libpcap file format has a field in its [global header called `network`](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat#Global_Header) that specifies the data link type. This corresponds to documentation over at the tcpdump project about various [Link-Layer Header Types](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html).

From there, you would be able to determine how many bytes the link layer consists (if any) and will be a sure fire way for you to parse pcap files created with the libpcap library.

I am not aware of a program options in the "libpcap family" that would allow you to just capture starting at the transport layer.

Comment: In particular, note that one of those link-layer header types is `LINKTYPE_RAW`; those packets start with an IPv4 or IPv6 header, so the upper nibble of the first byte of the packet will probably be 4 for IPv4 or 6 for IPv6.

Comment: I was surprised to see you didn't answer the question in the first place @GuyHarris.

Comment: And, if you've opened a device or saved capture file with libpcap, `pcap_datalink()` will return the `DLT_` value for the link-layer header type (which is *usually* the same as the `LINKTYPE_` value, but there are some exceptions - `LINKTYPE_RAW`/`DLT_RAW` is one of the exceptions, for annoying historical "different BSDs picked different numbers for `DLT_RAW`, but we want "raw IP" files from any platform to be readable on any other platform" reasons).